# extract properties with preg_replace

Tags: php, css, string, function, preg-replace

I want to extract all properties (and be able to manipulate them later on).

iow... everything in between `{}` will be extracted.

```
<?php

$css = <<<EOF

body {
z-index : 9;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
line-height: 10px;
}

p {
z-index: 9;
font-size: 10px;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
z-index: 2;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-size: 100%;
border: 0 none;
}

EOF;

echo preg_replace( '~{(.*)}~s', '$1<br/>' , $css );

?>
```

I'm expecting to get all properties extracted (and be able to manipulate them later on) with line break:

```
z-index : 9;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
line-height: 10px;

z-index: 9;
font-size: 10px;

z-index: 2;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-size: 100%;
border: 0 none;
```

Comment: Don't try to use a regular expression for this. https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular input string, try this-

```
echo preg_replace( '~.*?{(.*?)}~s', '$1<br/>' , $css );
```

Demo and explanation of the regex [Here](http://regex101.com/r/nT5lA3).
OUTPUT -

```
z-index : 9;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
line-height: 10px;
<br/>
z-index: 9;
font-size: 10px;
<br/>
z-index: 2;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-size: 100%;
border: 0 none;
<br/>
```

Comment: There are a few redundancies in this regex. `.*` means `0 or more anything`, the `?` after it makes it optional, which it already is. Since `.` also matches `{` and `}`, it will also match properties outside brackets.

Comment: Yes I was testing it and it working perfectly !!! I just want to understand why do I need to add .*? before the {

Comment: You only needed to capture the part inside the {} and uncapture everything else. If I did not use .* before the {, then body and p would also be included

Comment: @user3447293 Check out the link in the edit. That will explain the regex way better than I can.

Comment: @TVK It does make a difference. On the both the occasions, I want my regex to be non-greedy. Try the regex without the '?' in the link that I provided, I won't match properly.

Comment: @Kamehameha Ah I see, my apologies. Thanks for the explanation.